# Visual Studio 2022 Stopped Pushing to Git

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Pushing master Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error. Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access 'https:/: error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none  Failed to push the branch to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details. vs 2022

Answer (score 1):

If you installed (or reinstalled) Visual Studio to, say, the D: drive, the pointer to the certificate will change. Reinstalling Git desktop won't help in this case.
To Fix:  Find the old gitconfig file and open (in admin mode) in a suitable editor and change the path(s) to point to where the new installation is (or, in my case, just the drive letter).

```
C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig
```

The file would look something like so:

```
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[http]
    sslBackend = openssl
    sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
    symlinks = false
    editor = \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Microsoft VS Code\\\\bin\\\\code\" --wait
[pull]
    rebase = false
[credential]
    helper = manager-core
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
    useHttpPath = true
[init]
    defaultBranch = master
```

After the changes, it would look something like this:

```
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[http]
    sslBackend = openssl
    sslCAInfo = D:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
    symlinks = false
    editor = \"D:\\\\Program Files\\\\Microsoft VS Code\\\\bin\\\\code\" --wait
[pull]
    rebase = false
[credential]
    helper = manager-core
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
    useHttpPath = true
[init]
    defaultBranch = master
```

A lot of programs (including VS) will install something on the c: drive, and if you had the situation I had (not enough room on C: - so I uninstalled all the space hogging programs and reinstalled onto the D: drive), there is usually some sort of configuration file that points to the new location(s), so, it's a good idea to keep this in mind.

Answer (score -1):

install git https://git-scm.com/download/win again and it will fix the issue.